# How do I stop myself from redesigning my Silverlight screens? Is there a theme that looks like Sketchflow?

Tags: silverlight, themes

Whilst working in Silverlight I am always fighting the urge to work on the screen design rather than coding the behaviour (which is what I should be doing).  My cunning plan is to find a theme that looks something like MS SketchFlow or Balsamiq which will remind me of the draft nature of the screens whilst being somewhat prettier than the default look & feel of Silverlight.

Does anyone know of such a theme?  Alternatively can anyone give advise on how they overcame there design addiction :)

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... Work in Visual Studio rather than Blend?

Alternatively, those Sketchflow controls are just that, normal controls that are styled. If you create one of the demo sketchflow projects in blend you can just grab the style file, I think it's "SketchStyles.xaml" and reuse that where you need it.

(I used the 'KioskSketch' sample app btw)

Comment: If I can use SketchFlow's theme then that will be ideal.  I will definately give this a try.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: This worked like a charm.  One thing though, I had to add a reference to Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.SketchControls